# Floated list lowered below container when viewport resized in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm experimenting with responsive design and media queries to create containers which cater for different viewport sizes. My navigation bar consists of a logo div and a floated list with a container.

The issue I'm having is when the viewport is less than 640px and you resize it to more than 640px, the floated list disappears - refreshing fixes this though. I'm still trying to get head around media queries and how to use them with my site... any suggestions would be much appreciated!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pvPB/)

**HTML**

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x54"/>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Services</a></li>
            <li><a>Work</a></li>
            <li><a>Contact</a></li>
        </ul><!--
    --></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 290px; 
    max-width: 960px;  
    padding: 15px;
}

.navigation {
    width: 100%;
    background: #323232;
}

.navigation .container {
    padding: 15px;   
    position: relative;
}

.navigation .logo {
    height: 54px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.navigation ul {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 17px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
}   

.navigation li {
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navigation li:last-child {
    margin: 0;   
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) { /* Larger than 320px width less than 640px */
    .container { 
        width: 400px; 
    } 
}  

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) { /* Less than 640px */
    .navigation .logo {
        display: block; 
        text-align: center;
    }

    .navigation .container {
        padding: 3px 0;                                  
    }

    .navigation ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }


    .navigation li {
        display: block; 
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px 0;
        background: #000000
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) { /* Larger than 640px width less than 960px */
    .container { 
        width: 570px; 
    } 
}  

@media screen and (min-width: 960px) { /* Larger than 960px width */
    .container { 
        width: 960px; 
    }                
}
```

Comment: using your Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7pvPB/embedded/result/ and Firefox 28, it works perfect. Can't see any issue.

Comment: @dippas Sorry, should've added I'm using Chrome :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's behaving like this is because your `div.logo` comes before you float the `ul` so try putting `<div class="logo">` after `ul`.

However when you resize the browser, on smaller screen the logo will be below the menu, so what you can do is try to use `position:absolute` on `ul` and remove `float:right` from it, like this:

```
.navigation ul {
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .navigation ul {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So quick fix is remove `float:right` from your `.navigation ul`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

`overflow: hidden` to `.container`

`clear: both` to `.navigation ul`

and adding `float: left` to your logo when it is wider than mobile.